# Why doesn't this zoom functionality work in Google Maps iOS app?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, google-maps

I am trying to set up a way for the user to change the zoom of the map. Here's the code I have. What's the problem? Is there no implementation for invoking the zoom functionality? or is it that I set self.mapView.camera twice, in two different functions (viewDidLoad and ZoominOutMap)?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.
//Controls whether the My Location dot and accuracy circle is enabled.
CGFloat currentZoom = 14.0f;
self.mapView.myLocationEnabled = YES;

//adds type of map: kGMSTypeSatellite, kGMSTypeTerrain, kGMSTypeHybrid, kGMSTypeNormal
self.mapView.mapType = kGMSTypeHybrid;

//Shows the compass button on the map
self.mapView.settings.compassButton = YES;

//Shows the my location button on the map
self.mapView.settings.myLocationButton = YES;

//Sets the view controller to be the GMSMapView delegate
self.mapView.delegate = self;
GMSCameraPosition *manhattan = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:40.790278
                                                        longitude:-73.959722
                                                             zoom:14];
self.mapView.camera = manhattan;
}
 //setting up zoom
-(void)ZoominOutMap:(CGFloat)level
{
self.mapView.delegate = self;
GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:40.790218 longitude:-73.959722
                                                             zoom:level];
self.mapView.camera = camera;
}

-(void)zoomInMapView:(id)sender
{
CGFloat currentZoom;
currentZoom = currentZoom + 1;

[self ZoominOutMap:currentZoom];
}

-(void) zoomOutMapView:(id)sender
{
CGFloat currentZoom;
currentZoom = currentZoom - 1;

[self ZoominOutMap:currentZoom];
}

- (void)mapView:(GMSMapView *)mapView didTapAtCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)coordinate
{
NSLog(@"You tapped at %f,%f", coordinate.latitude, coordinate.longitude);
GMSMarker *marker = [[GMSMarker alloc] init];
//adds animation for adding marker
marker.appearAnimation = kGMSMarkerAnimationPop;
//draw marker on tapped position
marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(coordinate.latitude,coordinate.longitude);
marker.map = _mapView;
//set color of marker and make them draggable
marker.icon = [GMSMarker markerImageWithColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
[marker setDraggable: YES];

// Create a rectangular path
GMSMutablePath *rect = [GMSMutablePath path];
[rect addCoordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(coordinate.latitude,coordinate.longitude)];

// Create the polygon, and assign it to the map.
GMSPolygon *polygon = [GMSPolygon polygonWithPath:rect];
polygon.fillColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.25 green:0 blue:0 alpha:0.05];
polygon.strokeColor = [UIColor blackColor];
polygon.strokeWidth = 2;
polygon.map = _mapView;
}
```

Comment: your problem was solved or not?

Comment: no it was not;;

Comment: in your code where you call  zoomin,zoomout method?

Comment: no-where. where should I?

Comment: where you need to zoomin/zoomout functionality?

Comment: on the view controller. two buttons that enable to zoom in and out

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138088/discussion-between-konyv12-and-jigar).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forget to add action to the buttons:
**If buttons are added programatically :**

```
[zoomOut addTarget:self 
           action:@selector(zoomOutMapView:)
 forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[zoomOut addTarget:self 
           action:@selector(zoomInMapView:)
 forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

**For Storyboard :**
[image: connecting buttons to action]

```
//zoom controls 
- (IBAction)zoomOut:(id)sender { 

currentZoom = currentZoom - 1; 
[self zoomHandler:currentZoom]; 
} 

- (IBAction)zoomIn:(id)sender { 

currentZoom = currentZoom + 1; 
[self zoomHandler:currentZoom]; 
} 

- (void)zoomHandler:(CGFloat)level 
{ 
self.mapView.delegate = self; 
GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:40.790218 longitude:-73.959722 zoom:level]; 
self.mapView.camera = camera; 
}
```